# Node.js: Why should you return the result of a callback during error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, fs

Newbie to Node.js here. I'm learning Node.js via the tutorials at [NodeSchool.io](http://nodeschool.io/), and in one tutorial where we learned about modules, we were required to write something like this code:

```
// Some code...

function filteredLs(dir, ext, callback) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err); // return statement necessary here...
        callback(null, withExtension(files, ext)); // ...but not here
    })
}

module.exports = filteredLs;
```

My question is, in examples like these, why is it necessary to include the `return` statement when handling the error, but OK to omit when it's null? I don't see what use the return value of the function could have to `readdir` anyhow, since it happens after it finishes its work. Why does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `return` when calling a callback function is typically there to prevent the code that follows from running. The returned *value* is typically irrelevant.

That's why it's needed in the error case, so the `callback` call for the non-error case isn't also called.

It's not needed in the non-error case because it's already the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The error handling boilerplate you posted is indeed confusing. It uses a maximally-terse way of expressing the code, but is indeed confusing, and you are right that the return value is discarded. Thus my preferred boilerplate for clarity is

```
if (error) {
  callback(error)
  return
}
```

Which I feel is slightly clearer and the reduced concision is not that important to me (I type it with a macro anway).

I find this to make it clearer that there are 2 distinct intentions being expressed here:

1. Bubble the error back up to the caller
2. Exit the function as there's nothing else useful to be done. No return value because the callback protocol does not require one and the calling code does not need to and probably will not even capture the return value into a variable.